# Date format in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get the month from a date, The date in the database is saved as

```
2015-12-08
```

However its displaying as `2015 December 08`, I'm wanting to have it so that it shows only Dec and only Dec.

Heres the code that i have so far.

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>

<ul class="event-list" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
  <li class="event-date">
  <span class="event-date--month"><%= events.eventdate.strftime("%B") %></span>
  <span class="event-date--day">27</span>
  <span class="event-date--year">2015</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime), it should be `%b`. You also have another issue in your code: you are calling the method on an invalid object. The iterator element is `event`, not `events`.

```
<span class="event-date--month"><%= event.eventdate.strftime("%b") %></span>
```

Comment: It now says that undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass

Comment: It means `eventdate` is `nil` for that specific object. Make sure the value exists in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= event.eventdate.strftime("%b") %>
```

Lowercase b, shows abbreviated month.